selenium on WSL2 doesn't open firefox (ubuntu)
My code for web scraper is:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service as FirefoxService
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager
url = 'https://en.volleyballworld.com/volleyball/competitions/volleyball-nations-league/statistics/men/best-attackers/'

# Step 1: Setup Firefox options for headless mode
options = Options()
# options.add_argument('--headless')
# options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
# options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')

# Step 2: Setup the Firefox driver using webdriver_manager
service = FirefoxService(GeckoDriverManager().install())
print ('...')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=service, options=options)

# Step 3: Navigate to the website
driver.get(url)


firefox starts normaly from wsl terminal, but when runing this python program it says in firefox window error:
Your Firefox profile cannot be loaded. It may be missing or inaccessible.

if i wait for a minute new error in terminal shows:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/polona/git/Analiza-IFSC/get_data.py", line 20, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=service, options=options)
  File "/home/polona/git/Analiza-IFSC/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 71, in __init__
    super().__init__(command_executor=executor, options=options)
  File "/home/polona/git/Analiza-IFSC/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 212, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities)
  File "/home/polona/git/Analiza-IFSC/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 299, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, caps)["value"]
  File "/home/polona/git/Analiza-IFSC/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 354, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/polona/git/Analiza-IFSC/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 229, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: Failed to read marionette port

i tried rebooting, reinstalling. Weirdly it works on my friends computer.
